# STL basic_string length with null characters

Tags: c++, string, stl, stdstring

Why is it that you can insert a '\0' char in a std::basic_string and the .length() method is unaffected but if you call `char_traits<char>::length(str.c_str())` you get the length of the string up until the first '\0' character?

e.g.

```
string str("abcdefgh");
cout << str.length(); // 8
str[4] = '\0';
cout << str.length(); // 8
cout << char_traits<char>::length(str.c_str()); // 4
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Great question!

The reason is that a C-style string is defined as a sequence of bytes that ends with a null byte.  When you use `.c_str()` to get a C-style string out of a C++ `std::string`, then you're getting back the sequence the C++ string stores with a null byte after it.  When you pass this into `strlen`, it will scan across the bytes until it hits a null byte, then report how many characters it found before that.  If the `string` contains a null byte, then `strlen` will report a value that's smaller than the whole length of the string, since it will stop before hitting the real end of the string.

An important detail is that `strlen` and `char_traits<char>::length` are NOT the same function.  However, the C++ ISO spec for `char_traits<charT>::length` (§21.1.1) says that `char_traits<charT>::length(s)` returns the **smallest** `i` such that `char_traits<charT>::eq(s[i], charT())` is true.  For `char_traits<char>`, the `eq` function just returns if the two characters are equal by doing a `==` comparison, and constructing a character by writing `char()` produces a null byte, and so this is equal to saying "where is the first null byte in the string?"  It's essentially how `strlen` works, though the two are technically different functions.

A C++ `std::string`, however, it a more general notion of "an arbitrary sequence of characters."  The particulars of its implementation are hidden from the outside world, though it's probably represented either by a start and stop pointer or by a pointer and a length.  Because this representation does not depend on what characters are being stored, asking the `std::string` for its length tells you how many characters are there, regardless of what those characters actually are.

Hope this helps!

Comment: +1, and I'd just add that if you really want the internal null bytes, I believe one can use the `basic_string<>::data()` member function.

Comment: @dappawit- It's not that `c_str()` takes out the null bytes and that `data()` leaves them in; rather, they both have the null bytes in them, and `c_str()` guarantees that there's a null byte at the end and `data` doesn't.  The issue is how those bytes internal to the string are interpreted by functions that are used to a C-style string implementation.

Comment: Aha! You added the part I was about to put into an answer.

Comment: Which brings me to my next question, what is the point of Character Traits if the string class doesn't even seem to use it? (Don't answer that here)

Comment: @MattSmith- See my (long) answer to your other question.  The short version is that `std::string` does use the traits class, which gives you incredible flexibility.

Comment: Actually, my local `char_traits<char>::length(s)` just calls `strlen(s)` and returns the results. Likewise for `char_traits<wchar_t>::length(s)` and `wcslen(s)`

Comment: @mkb- That's perfectly legal and fine.  It's just that the spec doesn't mandate that this be the case.

Comment: If you're coming across this topic (over 9 years later) and you're using C++11, then `.data()` and `.c_str()` are now required to behave identically. `.data()` must end with a null character. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str