# how to terminate a string using null charector

Tags: c++, string

I have made a new string using the existing string.
Let say the initial string is

```
string a="sample";
```

and the newly created string is

```
string b=a;
```

Now I have placed the null character at the second index.

```
b[2]='\0';
```

when I try to out put the b string.

The output is shown as `saple`.

I want to end the string after index-1.

Is this behavior normal.If it is normal how to end the string after 1st index.

Thanks..

Comment: use [string::resize](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/resize/)

Comment: Don't mix `std::string` and "C-style" string concepts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`operator<<` is overloaded for [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt). The behavior will differ than if you do this:

```
char a[] = "sample";
char b[sizeof(a)];
strcpy(b, a);
b[2] = '\0';
std::cout << b;
```

or `std::cout << b.c_str();` (which calls the overload for a [`const char*`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2) rather than a `std::string`). The difference between the two overloads is that the overload for `const char*` calls [`std::char_traits<char>::length`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/char_traits/length) to determine how many characters to print (that is, up to the terminating null character). On the other hand, the overload for `std::string` uses `str.size()`. The size of a `std::string` includes any null characters embedded in it.<sup>1</sup>

In order to "truncate" a string, you can follow [@Wimmel's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26607888/how-to-terminate-a-string-using-null-charector#comment41827996_26607888) and use [`resize`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/resize):

```
std::string a = "sample";
std::string b = a;
b.resize(2);
std::cout << b;
```

<sup>1</sup> [STL basic_string length with null characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319556/stl-basic-string-length-with-null-characters)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what the standard defines should happen with what you are currently doing, but the proper way to do what you are trying to achieve is using std::string::substr() method like this:

```
b = a.substr(0, index-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is normal.
unlike C string, the lenght of `std::string` is not determined by `'\0'`, instead, there's a member variable recording its length. in the case, the string content is `73  61  00  70  6c  65`, thus, `b.length() == 6`, though there's a `'\0'` in it. you also can redirect the output into a file, and check the content, it is `73  61  00  70  6c  65`.
If you wanna to truncate the string, call `b.resize(2)`.