# Default-inserting into a vector isn't default initialization?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

One of the `std::vector` constructors is stipulated as, emphasis mine:

> `explicit vector(size_type n, const Allocator& = Allocator());`
>   *Effects:* Constructs a `vector` with `n` **default-inserted** elements using the specified allocator.
>   *Requires:* `T` shall be `DefaultInsertable` into `*this.`
>   *Complexity:* Linear in `n`.

Is default-insertion in any way related to default initialization? On this code:

```
std::vector<char> v(66000);
```

gcc 5.2 optimized produces:

```
  400d18:   bf d0 01 01 00          mov    $0x101d0,%edi
  400d1d:   48 83 c5 01             add    $0x1,%rbp
  400d21:   e8 1a fd ff ff          callq  400a40 <operator new(unsigned long)@plt>
  400d26:   31 f6                   xor    %esi,%esi
  400d28:   48 89 c3                mov    %rax,%rbx
  400d2b:   ba d0 01 01 00          mov    $0x101d0,%edx
  400d30:   48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
  400d33:   e8 38 fc ff ff          callq  400970 <memset@plt>
```

`memset`? What are *you* doing here? I thought this should simply do the equivalent of `new char[66000]`... that is, no initialization. clang 3.7 also emits a `memset`.

Why is there a `memset` here? Is this correct with respect to the standard? After all, if I wanted 66000 value-initialized chars I already have this constructor:

```
std::vector<char> v(66000, '\0');
```

Comment: Isn't the value initialization part a property of the allocator? IIRC there is an answer (from Howard Hinnant I think) showing how to write a custom allocator to avoid initialization.

Comment: @Praetorian No clue. This wasn't the behavior I was expecting ex ante, or given the wording. Hence the question.

Comment: Since the question is about Why is there a memset here Maybe because C++ is a better C,meaning that most of C++ STL uses C in its libstc++ library

Comment: @Joel, what? C++ is a better C?

Comment: @SergeyA, from the book of Bjarne Stroustrup, not fully quoted, but says C++ is like a better C.

Comment: @Joel, to me it sounds like a quote from one of my relatives - 'sausages  are better fish'. But than she doesn't like fish, and loves sausages.

Comment: Found [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21028912/241631) I was thinking of. So I guess if you really don't want initialization, use Casey's allocator.

Comment: @Praetorian Thanks! Seems questionable that this is the standard behavior.

Comment: That is standard behaviour, as my answer shows.

Comment: @SergeyA I'm not questioning that it *is* the standard behavior, rather whether it should be.

Comment: Than the question is 'should default allocator value-initialize objects it constructs'. Interesting question. I even wonder if this value-initialization is intentional or just a side-effect of empty parameter pack expansion. Totally possible that it is.

Comment: @SergeyA [So I thought I'd ask it](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35902965/2069064)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is correct behaviour. See 23.2.1:

> An element of X is default-inserted if it is initialized by evaluation of the expression `allocator_traits<A>::construct(m, p)`

Than, `allocator_traits<A>::construct` will call `a.construct(p, std::forward<Args>(args)...)`. Which, in turn, calls `::new((void *)p) U(std::forward<Args>(args)...)`, which in effect calls `new()`, which does value-initialization.

### Conclusion:

`memset()` is appropriate.

### Conclusion #2

Absent custom allocators, `std::vector` does not allow one an option to access uninitialized storage. Every object which is legitimately in vector was value-initialized.

Comment: So does the term "default inserted" equals "value-initialization"?

Comment: No the terms are not interchangeable. The effect of `default insertion` depends on the allocator.