# Should allocator construct() default initialize instead of value initializing?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, language-lawyer, allocator

As a followup to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35901417/2069064), the default allocator (`std::allocator<T>`) is required to implement `construct` as follows (according to [default.allocator]):

> ```
> template <class U, class... Args>
> void construct(U* p, Args&&... args);
> ```
>
> *Effects*: `::new((void *)p) U(std::forward<Args>(args)...)`

That is, always value-initialization. The result of this is that `std::vector<POD> v(num)`, for any pod type, will value-initialize `num` elements - which is more expensive than default-initializing `num` elements.

Why didn't<sup>†</sup> `std::allocator` provide a default-initializing additional overload? That is, something like (borrowed from [Casey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21028912/2069064)):

```
template <class U>
void construct(U* p) noexcept(std::is_nothrow_default_constructible<U>::value)
{
    ::new(static_cast<void*>(p)) U;
}
```

Was there a reason to prefer value initialization in call cases? It seems surprising to me that this breaks the usual C++ rules where we only pay for what we want to use.

---

<sup>†</sup>I assume such a change is impossible going forward, given that currently `std::vector<int> v(100)` will give you 100 `0`s, but I'm wondering why that is the case... given that one could just as easily have required `std::vector<int> v2(100, 0)` in the same way that there are differences between `new int[100]` and `new int[100]{}`.

Comment: See [P0040](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0040r3.html) adopted recently.

Comment: @FrankHB Does that paper change what `vector` would do here? It just adds algorithms to the standard library right?

Comment: Right. So it is not an answer, just a comment. It provides convenient interface to ease the implementation of your workaround.

Comment: Similar problem as `make_unique<T[]>` by the way.

Answer (score 3):

In C++03 Allocators `construct` member took two arguments: pointer and value which was used to perform copy-initialization:

> 20.1.6 Table 34
>
> `a.construct(p,t)`
>
> Effect:
>     `::new((void*)p) T(t)`

`construct` taking two parameters can be [traced back to 1994](http://www.stepanovpapers.com/Stepanov-The_Standard_Template_Library-1994.pdf) (pg. 18). As you can see, in orignal Stepanov concepts it wasn't part of allocator interface (it wasn't supposed to be configurable) and was present just as wrapper over placement new.

Only way to know for sure would to ask Stepanov himself, but I suppose that reason was following: if you want to construct something, you want to initialize it with specific value. And if you want your integers uninitializated, you can just omit `construct` call since it is not needed for POD types. Later `construct` and other related function were bundled into allocators and containers were parametrized on them introducing some loss of control on initialization for end user.

So it seems that lack of default initialization is for historical reasons: nobody though about its importance when C++ was standardized and later versions of the Standard would not introduce breaking change.

Comment: I think this is the right interpretation. For good or for bad it is a design choice of the container to always call construct(p), or just not to call it. The problem, I would say is that containers were implemented (?) as too eagerly always call construct. I think in modern C++ the choice is between not calling construct or calling std::start_lifetime_as https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/start_lifetime_as . whether this (or a equivalent) should be part of the allocator is a different question.