# using memset to initialize vector of structure which contains array

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, memset

I have following structure

```
struct a {
     int array[20]
     int array2[45]
}
```

I have created vector of this structure

```
vector<a> vec;
```

I have used this vec. Now i Want to initialize(setting all array values inside object in the vector element) to zero. How can i do it.?

Comment: What prevented you from reading the `std::vector` documentation? Why have you decided to use `memset`? What did you try after coming to that conclusion?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: std::vector will normally call the default constructor for the objects it contains.  Because this structure is just built-in types, the elements won't be zero initialized.

Comment: @MartinBonner: Yes, I am aware of that. The OP needs to _perform some research_ to find out how to zero out his elements. This question exhibits zero research effort. I am trying to prompt the OP to _perform some research_.

Comment: Why do you think he hasn't?  Constructing the vector with copies of a zero initialized object, giving the struct a default constructor, and memset are all plausible approaches - and memset may well be the best.

Comment: @MartinBonner `std::vector` will *value-initialize* its elements, not *default initialize them*. So they will be zero initialized. You can find that out by reading some documentation.

Comment: Of course, the vector is empty, so has no elements, making this question rather strange.

Comment: Hey @LightnessRacesinOrbit. I did research and then i asked question. Indeed I have found solution for it myself. I have created one temporary vector which vector<a> temp; and in this temp vector i have initailized all array elements to zero one time. and use it later to as b=temp;

Comment: @WinchesterAllpesh You don't even need to do that. To create a vector of 10 zero initialized elements, `vector<a> vec(10);`.

Comment: I don't want to create new vector i just want to reuse that space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that this is a much more interesting question than it first appears.

**tl;dr:** If you are using a C++03 or later compiler, you don't need to bother.

You need to understand the difference between [*value initialization*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) and [*default initialization*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization).  Basically value initialization will set all the elements to zero, and default initialization wil leave them all alone.  If any of the default elements of the structure (recursively) have a user defined default constructor, then both value and default initialization will call that.

Note that value initialization is *much* better than `memset` to zero because

- It will call default constructors
- It will correctly initialize floating point (to 0.0) and pointers (to NULL).  Although `memset` will *probably* do that on your implementation, it isn't guaranteed to.

The normal way to create a vector with *n* elements is just to call:

```
std::vector<a> vec(n);
```

**C++98**

this will call

```
std::vector<a>::vector(size_type count, 
                       const T& value = T(),
                       const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());
```

The `value` object will be default constructed, and you will need to initialize the elements somehow.  The best way to do that, is to provide a properly value initialized value to be copied.  So:

```
const static a azeroed;  // Because this is static, it will be value initialized
std::vector<a> vec(20,azeroed);
```

Technical note:  The C++98 standard doesn't contain the term "value initialization", but the initialization of `azeroed` is identical.

**C++03**

The same vector constructor is called, but from C++03, the `value` argument *is* value initialized (so everything in the garden is rosy).

**C++11**

The call is to

```
std::vector<a>::vector(size_type count);
```

which value initializes the elements directly.

**C++14**

The call is to

```
std::vector<a>::vector(size_type count, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());
```

(basically, they realized they forgot the allocator argument).  There is a very subtle difference here, in that the elements are constructed by calls to `Allocator::construct`, and although the default allocator will value initialize the elements, it is possible to provide a custom version which doesn't (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21028912/273767)).  If you are doing that, you almost certainly know what you are doing.

**Conclusion**

- Unless you are using a real C++98 compiler, you don't need to call memset
- Providing an explicitly value initialized value to the vector constructor is safer than calling memset.
- memset may not properly initialize non-integral built-in values (although it probably will).
- memset will *definitely* clobber anything will a proper constructor.  This is a huge maintenance hazard.  If a maintenance programmer changes the structure so it is no longer POD, the code will still *compile* - it will just do the wrong thing.
- There is a lot to be said for just giving the struct a proper default constructor, and then you never have to worry about whether any of the elements are initialized, even if you have a local copy.

Comment: The problem with this is that if you ever change the types, potentially making the struct not POD any more, this'll just silently continue zeroing everything out which could be a critical bug. I found one of those in production once that had caused intermittent crashes for years, costing a customer thousands. Prefer a type-safe solution in C++, especially when teaching.

Comment: This is not  a great example. The shown initialization results in all of the elements having zero initialized data without the call to `memset`.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Chapter and verse please?  Given the definition of the struct, the default construction *wont* zero initialize it.  (Or have I got that wrong?)

Comment: As I said in another comment, `std::vector` value initializes the elements.

Comment: @MartinBonner, For a specific reference, [vector.cons] says default-inserted elements.  [container.requirements.general] clarifies this to be `allocator_traits<A>::construct(m, p)`. From there, [allocator.traits.members] transforms it into `a.construct(p, std::forward<Args>(args)...) ` (because this is the default allocator), and  [allocator.members] says this is `::new((void *)p) U(std::forward<Args>(args)...)`, which is value-initialization when the args pack is empty. It's a bit roundabout, and can change with the allocator, but should be true in nearly every case.

Comment: I thought I had already commented. This is a useful improvement in C++11.  I will edit (rewrite) the answer when I have a proper computer to hand.

Comment: ... and it turns out that it was actually a useful improvement in C++03

Comment: C++98 doesn't have value-initialization but your comment in C++98 code snippet says it does

Comment: It isn't called value init in that version, but the initialization of a static behaves like what is called value initialization in later standards

Answer (score 1):

Reading the comments, there's code you haven't shown that populated your vector.  Now you'd like to reuse the storage instead of creating a new one, and you want to re-initialize it.

The canonical answer for any algorithm for any C++ container is likely found among the standard algorithms.  In this case, [std::fill](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/fill/).  Initialize your structure how you like, and copy that to your vector.  Along these lines:

```
a A = {0};
std::fill(vec.begin(), vec.end(), A);
```

If you're tempted to say that's not fast enough, check.  I think you'll find it's quite efficient.  The above code is absolutely safe, and works for any correctly initialized argument to `fill`.  I doubt it can be made faster without making some assumptions about the implementation of `a`.