# Fastest way to copy a vector with specific changes in C++

Tags: c++, vector

I want to copy a vector while setting an elements property to zero. I have a `std::vector<PLY>` vector that holds a specific number of the following struct elements:

```
struct PLY{
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
}
```

What is the fastest way to create a copy of this vector where each PLY element has a `z-value` of `0`? Is there a faster way then creating a copy of the vector and then iterating over each element to set the new z-value?

Comment: If you define a default ctor that initialises each element to `0` then simply defining the vector with an initial size will default each struct element to `0`

Comment: PLY() : x(0),y(0),z(0) add this default ctor to your struct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> what is the fastest way to... ?

#### first answer

Test it. Memory architectures do surprising things.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>

struct PLY
{
    PLY() : x(0), y(0), z(0) {}
    PLY(float x, float y, float z) : x(x), y(y), z(z) {}
    float x, y , z;
};



template<class F>
std::vector<PLY> test(const char* name, std::vector<PLY> samples, F f)
{
    using namespace std::literals;
    std::vector<PLY> result;
    result.reserve(samples.size());

    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    f(result, samples);

    auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    using fns = std::chrono::duration<long double, std::chrono::nanoseconds::period>;
    using fms = std::chrono::duration<long double, std::chrono::milliseconds::period>;
    using fs = std::chrono::duration<long double, std::chrono::seconds::period>;

    auto interval = fns(end - start);
    auto time_per_sample = interval / samples.size();
    auto samples_per_second = 1s / time_per_sample;

    std::cout << "testing " << name << '\n';
    std::cout << " sample size        : " << samples.size() << '\n';
    std::cout << " time taken         : " << std::fixed << fms(interval).count() << "ms\n";
    std::cout << " time per sample    : " << std::fixed << (interval / samples.size()).count() << "ns\n";
    std::cout << " samples per second : " << std::fixed << samples_per_second << "\n";

    return result;
}

struct zero_z_iterator : std::vector<PLY>::const_iterator
{
    using base_class = std::vector<PLY>::const_iterator;
    using value_type = PLY;

    using base_class::base_class;

    value_type operator*() const {
        auto const& src = base_class::operator*();
        return PLY{ src.x, src.y, 0.0 };
    }
};

int main()
{

    test("transform", std::vector<PLY>(1000000), [](auto& target, auto& source)
         {
             std::transform(source.begin(), source.end(),
                            std::back_inserter(target),
                            [](auto& ply) {
                                return PLY { ply.x, ply.y, ply.z };
                            });
         });

    test("copy and reset z", std::vector<PLY>(1000000), [](auto& target, auto& source)
         {
             std::copy(source.begin(), source.end(),
                       std::back_inserter(target));
             for (auto& x : target)
             {
                 x.z = 0;
             }
         });

    test("hand_roll", std::vector<PLY>(1000000), [](auto& target, auto& source)
         {
             for(auto& x : source) {
                 target.emplace_back(x.x, x.y, 0.0);
             }
         });

    test("assign through custom iterator", std::vector<PLY>(1000000), [](auto& target, auto& source)
         {
             target.assign(zero_z_iterator(source.begin()),
                                           zero_z_iterator(source.end()));
         });


    test("transform", std::vector<PLY>(100000000), [](auto& target, auto& source)
         {
             std::transform(source.begin(), source.end(),
                            std::back_inserter(target),
                            [](auto& ply) {
                                return PLY { ply.x, ply.y, ply.z };
                            });
         });

    test("copy and reset z", std::vector<PLY>(100000000), [](auto& target, auto& source)
         {
             std::copy(source.begin(), source.end(),
                       std::back_inserter(target));
             for (auto& x : target)
             {
                 x.z = 0;
             }
         });

    test("hand_roll", std::vector<PLY>(100000000), [](auto& target, auto& source)
         {
             for(auto& x : source) {
                 target.emplace_back(x.x, x.y, 0.0);
             }
         });

    test("assign through custom iterator", std::vector<PLY>(100000000), [](auto& target, auto& source)
         {
             target.assign(zero_z_iterator(source.begin()),
                           zero_z_iterator(source.end()));
         });
}
```

#### sample results

```
testing transform
 sample size        : 1000000
 time taken         : 7.495685ms
 time per sample    : 7.495685ns
 samples per second : 133410088.604310
testing copy and reset z
 sample size        : 1000000
 time taken         : 3.436614ms
 time per sample    : 3.436614ns
 samples per second : 290984090.735823
testing hand_roll
 sample size        : 1000000
 time taken         : 3.289287ms
 time per sample    : 3.289287ns
 samples per second : 304017253.587176
testing assign through custom iterator
 sample size        : 1000000
 time taken         : 2.563334ms
 time per sample    : 2.563334ns
 samples per second : 390116933.649692
testing transform
 sample size        : 100000000
 time taken         : 768.941767ms
 time per sample    : 7.689418ns
 samples per second : 130048859.733744
testing copy and reset z
 sample size        : 100000000
 time taken         : 880.893920ms
 time per sample    : 8.808939ns
 samples per second : 113521046.892911
testing hand_roll
 sample size        : 100000000
 time taken         : 769.276240ms
 time per sample    : 7.692762ns
 samples per second : 129992315.894223
testing assign through custom iterator
 sample size        : 100000000
 time taken         : 689.493098ms
 time per sample    : 6.894931ns
 samples per second : 145034084.155546
```

#### final answer

Assign through a custom transform iterator.

#### a gift for your toolbox

```
template<class Container, class Iter, class TransformFunction>
void assign_transform(Container& target, Iter first, Iter last, TransformFunction func)
{
    struct transform_iterator : Iter
    {
        using base_class = Iter;
        using value_type = typename Iter::value_type;

        transform_iterator(Iter base, TransformFunction& f)
        : base_class(base), func(std::addressof(f))
        {}

        value_type operator*() const {
            auto const& src = base_class::operator*();
            return (*func)(src);
        }
        TransformFunction* func;
    };

    target.assign(transform_iterator(first, func),
                  transform_iterator(last, func));
}
```

use like so:

```
         assign_transform(target, source.begin(), source.end(),
                          [](auto& from)
         {
             return PLY(from.x, from.y, 0.0);
         });
```

Comment: Nice work! Your transform and assign through custom iterator versions above don't set `z` to `0`, but it doesn't seem to affect the results much.

Comment: @TartanLlama will fix that. thanks. also missed a `#include <algorithm>`. clang makes you so lazy...

Comment: And interestingly, the transform version is waaaay faster with Clang 3.8 than GCC 6.1.1 on my machine.

Comment: @TartanLlama both libstdc++, or is your clang libc++ like mine?

Answer (score 8):

You could use [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform):

```
std::vector<PLY> zeroed{};
zeroed.reserve(other_vec.size()); //pre-allocate the storage
std::transform(other_vec.begin(), other_vec.end(), std::back_inserter(zeroed), 
           [](auto e){ e.z = 0.f; return e; });
```

Comment: `zeroed.begin(),`  Should be: `std::back_inserter(zeroed)`.  You only called `reserve`, not `resize`.

Comment: just wondering, is the rvalue reference necessary? wouldn't a lvalue reference do it?

Comment: @user1810087 It's not an rvalue reference, it's a forwarding reference due to the type deduction. It doesn't really make a difference in this case, but it's the most generic way to do this kind of thing as it will handle proxy objects.

Comment: Wouldn't that change values in `other_vec`? Type deduction will deduce l-value reference, and then you will set `z` to 0. It seems that OP wants to leave values in original vector unchanged.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot Wow, I'm really on the ball today </sarcasm>. Fixed.

Comment: in testing (above), much to my dismay, `std::transform` is by far the slowest way. :(

Answer (score 3):

If there is, your compiler will probably find it. Write the code as simply and clearly as you possibly can. That will give the compiler the best chance to optimize the copy and the loop together, if that makes sense on your platform.

Comment: Ordinarily I'd say the same thing. But testing indicates that an assignment through a transform iterator is very much faster. I think the std containers could use an `assign_through_transform` method to make this idiomatic. See tests above.

Comment: @RichardHodges That seems to me to be the simplest and clearest way, giving the compiler the best chance to optimize the copy and the loop together.

Answer (score 3):

There are two problems with the vector with the default allocator:

1. If the vector is resized to a greater size each element of it is initialized and the initialization has cost,
2. When memory reserved for the vector and elements are inserted into it, because the size of the vector is updated there is a cost for each insertion.

To get rid of this as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21028299/is-this-behavior-of-vectorresizesize-type-n-under-c11-and-boost-container) a custom allocator can be used to refuse to do any initialization. When a vector is created with the desired size `memcpy` or for loop can be used to copy the data:

```
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>
template <class T>
class no_init_alloc
    : public std::allocator<T>
{
public:
    using std::allocator<T>::allocator;

    template <class U, class... Args> void construct(U*, Args&&...) {}
};
struct PLY
{
    float x, y , z;
};
int main()
{
    std::vector<PLY> source(1000000);
    //create a vector with the custom allocator refusing any initialization
    std::vector<PLY, no_init_alloc<PLY>> target(source.size());
    //then we can use memcpy approach
    {
        memcpy(target.data(), source.data(), source.size() * sizeof(source.front()));
        for(auto& t : target) t.z = 0.0f;
    }
    // or simple for loop approach
    {
         size_t sz = target.size();
         for(size_t i = 0; i < sz; ++i) {
            target[i].x = source[i].x;
            target[i].y = source[i].y;
            target[i].z = 0.0f;
         }
    }

}
```

using @Richard Hodges 's benchmark with -O2 optimization the result is:

> CLNAG:

```
testing transform
 sample size        : 1000000
 time taken         : 8.363995ms
 time per sample    : 8.363995ns
 samples per second : 119560090.602637
testing assign through custom iterator
 sample size        : 1000000
 time taken         : 7.162974ms
 time per sample    : 7.162974ns
 samples per second : 139606816.945029
testing no_init_alloc_memcpy
 sample size        : 1000000
 time taken         : 6.918533ms
 time per sample    : 6.918533ns
 samples per second : 144539312.018892
testing no_init_alloc_for
 sample size        : 1000000
 time taken         : 6.383721ms
 time per sample    : 6.383721ns
 samples per second : 156648450.018414
```

> GCC:

```
testing transform
 sample size        : 1000000
 time taken         : 12.083038ms
 time per sample    : 12.083038ns
 samples per second : 82760643.473934
testing assign through custom iterator
 sample size        : 1000000
 time taken         : 6.188324ms
 time per sample    : 6.188324ns
 samples per second : 161594641.780230
testing no_init_alloc_memcpy
 sample size        : 1000000
 time taken         : 3.000699ms
 time per sample    : 3.000699ns
 samples per second : 333255684.758785
testing no_init_alloc_for
 sample size        : 1000000
 time taken         : 1.979482ms
 time per sample    : 1.979482ns
 samples per second : 505182669.001284
```

**final answer:**

Use a custom non initializing allocator with simple for loop.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a job for [std::transform](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) with a little lambda to do the transformation on each element.