# Modern C++ containers with default initialization

Tags: c++, stl, containers, c++17, c++20

Is it still possible to change the initialization in C++ containers to default initialization instead of value initialization?
There is a method below that modifies the allocator to change it, but `std::allocator<T>::construct` is deprecated in C++17, also it doesn't work with PMR allocators.

[Is this behavior of vector::resize(size_type n) under C++11 and Boost.Container correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21028299/is-this-behavior-of-vectorresizesize-type-n-under-c11-and-boost-container/21028912#21028912)

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator/construct

Comment: `std::allocator<T>::construct` is deprecated (and removed in C++20). That doesn't meant that you can't provide your own allocator with a custom `construct`.

Answer (score 4):

Adding a member `construct` to your custom allocator is still the correct way to get this customization.

The only reason it was deprecated/removed in `std::allocator` is because `std::allocator` doesn't need this customization.  `std::allocator_traits::construct` does the right thing for `std::allocator`.  It was left in for awhile for backwards compatibility with code that directly called `std::allocator<T>::construct` instead of `std::allocator_traits<std::allocator>::construct`.

C++20 forces clients to use the more modern `std::allocator_traits<std::allocator>::construct`.  And clients of your custom allocator should also access your `construct` via `allocator_traits`.